# User friendly message with http status code 500

Tags: http

Hi I have developed an application using `java` that sends a `http status code 500` to the browser if something went wrong on server side.

But I want to display a user friendly message along with `http status 500`.

Can you help me out what http header I can use to send and user friendly messages along with `http status 500`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send a regular HTML response body. (It may require to be > ~500 bytes otherwise old IE versions might replace it with something builtin).